# Конфликт полей в моделях django

Tags: python, django

**Django выдает ошибку** `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'id' in class 'User' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'UserPermissionMixin'.`

**Модель User:**

```
class User(AbstractUser, UserPermissionMixin):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

**Модель UserPermissionMixin:**

```
class UserPermissionMixin(PermissionsMixin):
    groups = None
    user_permissions = None

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        queryset = self.user_permissions.filter(codename=perm) | UserPermission.objects.filter(
            group__user=self,
            codename=perm,
        )
        return queryset.exists()

    def get_all_permissions(self, obj=None):
        return self.user_permissions.all() | UserPermission.objects.filter(group__user=self)
```

Я знаю, что такая ошибка возникает, если в наследуемых классах тоже было бы поле "id" ([пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57029010/django-core-exceptions-fielderror-local-field-email-in-class-user-clashes-w)), но здесь оно есть только в классе "User"

Comment: поле  id неявным образом задается по умолчанию у моделей в качестве primary key. так что, оно _есть_ у родительского класса.

Comment: @strawdog, но что делать, если я хочу его переопределить в User?

Comment: а зачем, интересно?

Comment: @strawdog, Чтобы оно было в форме uuid

Comment: ну заведите себе еще один user-defined id в модели, под другим именем. sqlite все равно не имеет встроенного типа uuid, его задает django и хранит в таблице как char(32). то есть, и так и эдак поменять встроенный тип int не получится. кроме того, уверен, для уникальности вам вполне хватит встроенного 64-bit signed int - в противном случае вам, возможно, стоит вообще задуматься о смете базы данных.

Comment: @strawdog, спасибо